# On element hover show description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have few elements in a row. I want to display just img and when you hover on it the description would be shown below. It works fine but when description is shown the whole div expands and it mess up the row. How can i set it to be

- exact same width and height all the time
- the text should just display on pic below.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.details').show(500);
        $(this).addClass('higlighted');
    }, function() {
        $('.details').hide(500);
        $(this).removeClass('higlighted');
    })
});
```

```css
.products {
    justify-content: center;
}

.products-description {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.products-description h1 {
    font-family: 'Homenaje', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.products-description p {
    font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.box {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

.box .details {
    display: none;
    transition: 1s;
}

.box .details p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.higlighted {
    background: rgba(98, 192, 23);
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row products">
            <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details" id="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row products">
            <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details" id="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I think your Event is being triggered again and again when you hover over the .box. So the .show(500) keeps being triggered

Answer (score 3):

You can set the width of `.higlighted` as the width of `.box`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.details').show(500);
        $(this).addClass('higlighted');
        var w = $('.box').width();
        $('.higlighted').css({width: `${w}`});
    }, function() {
        $('.details').hide(500);
        $(this).removeClass('higlighted');
    })
});
```

```css
.products {
    justify-content: center;
}

.products-description {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.products-description h1 {
    font-family: 'Homenaje', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.products-description p {
    font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.box {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

.box .details {
    display: none;
    transition: 1s;
}

.box .details p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.higlighted {
    background: rgba(98, 192, 23);
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row products">
    <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details" id="details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row products">
    <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details" id="details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So tell me how can i achive that description is displayed on some of the place of pic belowe ? I just don't want to expend height by showing description.

Comment: @Buszek, do you mean inside of a fixed area (height, width)?

Comment: Yes i mean inside of a fixed area, so the description won't push pic belowe further. The pic should stay in fixed area and description should be display on lets say half of a pic belowe.

Comment: @Buszek and what if the description is more than the static height which is given?

Comment: @XenioGracias than I want description to be displayed on some of the place of picture belowe.

Comment: @Buszek width will increase if thats okay with you.

Comment: It's wierd becouse this function still push pictures lower on my site. What can cause problem ? Edit: can it be becouse of bootstrap ?

Answer (score 2):

used `css` to achieve it.

```
.box:hover .details{
    display: block;
        transition: 1s;
}

.box:hover{
    background: rgba(98, 192, 23);
    transition: 1s;
}
```

let me know if anything else needs to be changed. thanks

```css
.products {
    justify-content: center;
}

.products-description {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.products-description h1 {
    font-family: 'Homenaje', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.products-description p {
    font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.box {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

.box .details {
    display: none;
    transition: 1s;
}

.box .details p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.higlighted {
    background: rgba(98, 192, 23);
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s;
}

.box:hover .details{
    display: block;
        transition: 1s;
}

.box:hover{
    background: rgba(98, 192, 23);
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row products">
            <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details" id="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row products">
            <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details" id="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your css property `transition: 1s` that causing you trouble because you're doing that with jQuery as well with `hide(500)` and `show(500)`.

If you're doing the jQuery way, you just have to remove the css property.

The height is adjusting dynamically because of the transition. If you don't want that, either do not use transition or do it @Mamun's way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.details').show(500);
        $(this).addClass('higlighted');
    }, function() {
        $('.details').hide(500);
        $(this).removeClass('higlighted');
    })
});
```

```css
.products {
    justify-content: center;
}

.products-description {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.products-description h1 {
    font-family: 'Homenaje', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.products-description p {
    font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.box {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

.box .details {
    display: none;
}

.box .details p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.higlighted {
    background: rgba(98, 192, 23);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row products">
            <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details" id="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row products">
            <div class="col-lg-1 box" id="box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details" id="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 box">
                <div class="imgBox">
                    <img class="product-mouseover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Without transition i have no effect of animation with just jquery. Don't know why, also tried .slideDown() but it wasn't working too.

Comment: Yes, you'll have better luck with jQuery UI library but I think it's more easier to go with a css oriented solution in your case